# Why does OmniAuth pass requests onto the next middleware?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, middleware, omniauth

[OmniAuth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) works great, but I've noticed when using it in a Rails v2.3.6 app that it **passes requests on to the next Rack middleware**, even though it ends up handling the request itself, and responding with a Redirect.

Code Excerpt: (from [Github](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/blob/master/oa-core/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb#L31))

```
if current_path == request_path && OmniAuth.config.allow....
  status, headers, body = *call_app!
  @response = Rack::Response.new(body, status, headers)
  request_phase
elsif current_path == callback_path
  callback_phase
else
  ...
end
```

And my app, upon being passed the `/auth/provider` request, throws an exception and returns a 404.  The user doesn't see this, but `ExceptionNotifier` and the logs do.  To deal with this, I've created another middleware that just responds with `[200,{},[]]` for all paths like `/auth/provider_name`.

**Why does OmniAuth pass the request down the middleware stack?**

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want OmniAuth to pass the next middleware you just have to change the order of the middlewares. 
Example

Middleware_1
Middleware_2
...
OmniAuth
Your_APP

and it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3.1.1 I got such problem.

When you have a route in your app that respond to `auth/:provider_name` and not returns 404 error, it will be used instead of following omniauth flow.

To solve you need to remove it or force to return responce with 404 status